# How can I get the same format of cells in my script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-cell-format

I've made a script, but I need the numbers off 3 rows to be on percentage and I also want to use only 2 decimals and format the date (one of my table colums) as "yyyy-MM-dd".

this is my actual script:

```
function getdata() 
{

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("name");
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(10,4,1,9);
  var colors = dataRange.getBackgrounds();
  

// Auxiliar

  var sp = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var pont = sp.getRange("cell").getValue();
  Logger.log(pont)

  // Se é o dia D
  if(pont==true)
  {
  var tab = ss.getSheetByName("sheet");
  var datavalues = tab.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(datavalues)

  // Improve later
  
  var html = '<font size=0.5>(This is an automatic message.  If you should not be receiving it, contact the ownwer)</font> \
  <br><br>\
   <b>HEADER</b>  \
  <br><br>\
  Body <font size=1.0>(DB disponible <a href="link">here</a>)</font> \
  <br><br> ' + '<table>';

  if(datavalues.length>0)
  {
      for(var i=0; i<datavalues.length;i++) // counting the rows of the table
        {
        html+= '<tr style = bgcolor="Blue">'; // html = html + something
        for(var j = 0; j<datavalues[i].length;j++)
        // check if the row is header of the table or normal row
          {
            if(i==0)
              {
                html+= Utilities.formatString('<td bgcolor="LightBlue"; \
                style = "\
                border:0px solid black; \
                border-collapse: collapse; \
                text-align:center; \
                font-family:questrial; \
                font-size:100% \
                " <th>%s</th></td>', datavalues[i][j]);          
                
            } else
                {
                  html+=Utilities.formatString('<td \
                  style = "border:1px solid black; \
                  border-collapse: collapse; \
                  border-style:none none dashed none; \
                  text-align:center; \
                  font-family:questrial; \
                  font-size:90% \
                  " > %s</td>', datavalues[i][j]);
                } 
          }
    }
  html+='<table>'
  }
  return html;
  }
}

function sendEmail()
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("link");

// ponteiro

  var sp = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var pont = sp.getRange("cell").getValue();
  Logger.log(pont)

  // Se é o dia D'
  // , emails 

  if(pont==true)
  {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "email@email.com",
    subject: "Test",
    htmlBody: getdata()
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the data as text strings in the format the data shows in the spreadsheet, replace this line:

```
  var datavalues = tab.getDataRange().getValues();
```

...with this:

```
  var datavalues = tab.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
```

Then format the data in the spreadsheet the way you want it to appear.

To get numbers with exactly two decimals, use **Format > Number > Number**.

To get dates in the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard date format `yyyy-MM-dd`, use **Format > Number > Custom date and time > 1930-08-05**.